# Question/Answer Review Lists

Tags: discussion, review

The new SO reviewing feature is very efficient, but the one aspect it isn't efficient is in looking for posts for flagging for moderator approval, because it's spam, not an answer, etc.  The old review lists was a great feature because you can review 30 items at a time looking for items that may need flagging.

Is there any feature left in SO that allows this, or is every review feature always analyzing a single post at a time?

Comment: Is there a reason you're specifically combing through looking for things to flag?

Comment: To complete the Deputy and Marshal flags, and it can be quicker to review items when you have them in a list form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize that SO does still have a relevant list for this, which is: https://stackoverflow.com/tools